# why does EF6 create this crazy migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 6.1.3.

here's my initial schema:

```cs
[Table("Children")]
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

[Table("Parents")]
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

when I change the multiplicity of the association to (I'm using edmx to do this IRL, but this example illustrates the problem):

```cs
[Table("Children")]
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}


[Table("Parents")]
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

as far as I can tell, the only necessary DB schema change is the nullability of the Children.Parent column. however, EF generates this craziness:

```cs
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Children", new[] { "Parent_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Children", "Id");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Children", name: "Parent_Id", newName: "Id");
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Children");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Children", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Children", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Children", "Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Children", "Id");
    }
```

which obviously makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

WTF is going on here?

Comment: Did you notice you also changed it from a collection of Children to a single Child?

Comment: Auto generated migration code is not written in stone, EF do the best it can when generating this code. It is up to you to get it fine-tuned with your data store.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel yes, that was intentional. there is no database schema changed required for that change, though.

Comment: @E-Bat i understand that i can change it. but i have never seen EF generate such an obviously broken migration as this. this one doesn't even run. it has two consecutive identical lines. it drops the primary key, twice, two different ways! really, there's nothing right about it, except maybe the first and last lines.

Comment: Help EF to generate a more accurate migration. You need to decorate your POCO's properties with ForeignKey, ColumnName etc...

Comment: actually, these are exactly the queries you would create in EF's place (if you had to compute them). Since there is no ParentId necessary anymore (because it's one-to-one and EF does these on PK=FK), it is dropped with the index on it. To keep the relationships intact, EF has to rename the parent id's to the PK of the table, so these are rows 3+4. And the rest is just consistency - FK is no longer nullable and the newly created column has to be PK and indexed.